# How to use WP_Query() on single.php?

Tags: wp-query, loop, single, memory

I'm using `WP_Query()` to pull out a few posts under a specific category "Featured" to display at the bottom of any post.

So I added `<?php if (function_exists('getEditorPicks')) getEditorPicks();?>` in single.php.

In functions.php, I have

```
wp_reset_postdata();
    $args = array('cat' => 4176, 'posts_per_page' => 5);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    //return $query->query_vars;
    if ($query->post_count>2) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post;
            echo the_title();
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

However, it takes forever for the page to load now and it simply exhausts memory in the end.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query->the_post;
```

should be:

```
$query->the_post();
```

The first is trying to fetch a property named `the_post` rather than invoking the function so the post never advances, and your loop is infinite.